# Should I always load keyStore explicitely in my WebClient for authorized services?

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have a java keystore with which I can connect to a protected https third-party service. I use this keystore explicitely in my code when I initialize my web client:

```
// Solution #1
String password = "changeit";
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(new File("src/main/resources/keystore.jks"), password.toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, password.toCharArray())
    .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, (hostname, session) -> true);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
    .build();
```

With this approach, everything works fine.

But I also know that there is a possibility to specify the system variables `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`. So I was expecting an alternative solution to the code above will also work:

```
// Solution #2
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "src/main/resources/keystore.jks");
System.setProperty( "javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit"); 
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

where I create a default web client without constructing SSLContext with my keystore explicitly. I have expected that the default web client will take somehow the keystore automatically from `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`. But it seems it did not take and this solution did not work for me.

So I wonder what is the purpose of the use of system property `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`? How it can be useful? What is the best practice here?

Comment: What makes you think that resources under the `src` directory will be there at runtime?

Comment: It is just an example of the path. But I just assume that the path to my keystore file is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the first solution, but you have to remove the password as a `String`, the password should be either in your `properties` file that is loaded at runtime, or specify it as an environment variable when you start the JVM.

I would say that the main point is that the password should not be in the code.

For the second solution you might want to check the `trustStore` environment variables.

https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslserver.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the truststore `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` for the public cert to provide to the external service.  `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` is for storing your private cert when running on https.

```
// Your private cert location
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", env.getProperty(SSL_KEYSTORE));
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", env.getProperty(SSL_KEYSTORE_PASS));
// Public cert location
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", env.getProperty(SSL_TRUSTSTORE));
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", env.getProperty(SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASS));
```

Also, I would recommend loading the properties (especially passwords) from a separate properties file, as mentioned by Léo Schneider.

**UPDATE**
To your question regarding usefulness of `javax.net.ssl` properties, these properties are an alternative to define the truststore and keystore properties. It is useful b/c not all libraries allow for SSLContext as input where it may be needed (for example legacy libraries that don't support ssl). Furthermore, these properties can also be defined directly from the command line, increasing usability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is still not clear for me - what for `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` argument is from a practical point of view? In any case, I should always create a ssl context in web client.  How `javax.net.ssl.keyStore` helps me here? I can just use a direct path to my Keystore as I did in `Solution #1` (password out of question).

Comment: `javax.net.ssl` properties are an alternative to define the truststore and keystore properties.  It is useful b/c not all libraries allow for SSLContext as input where it may be needed.  Furthermore, these properties can also be defined directly from the command line.

Comment: Ok, I ran my app with `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12` but my requests stay unauthorized until I define custom `sslContext` and put it explicitly in `httpClient` (as I did in `Solution #1`). I was hoping that with these properties I can escape the custom definition of `sslContext`, but it seems that it is impossible. So these properties do not really helpful, I will just use them only to get values and then do all the work of defining `sslContext` by myself. Or I miss something?

Comment: As I mentioned in the first line, you need to use `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` properties, NOT `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`.  Keystore is for storing YOUR certificates, so that the server can verify your identity....Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: No, I need exactly `keyStore` as my request to the remote server should be formed with the identity certificate and private key (from them I have generated my `keyStore`). The remote server has only my `public` key, so my requests can be authenticated.

Comment: Identity Certificate & Private Key?  They should be the same (identity cert = private key).  Also, you can't send private key (that would be unsafe)  Just FYI.  Some other notes:  1) If you are connecting to https, you need to get their public key and also provide the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` props, or enable accept all connections by default (unsafe, not recommended).  2) Make sure the keystore location is correct...you are providing two different values in your post vs. comments.

Comment: Also, I mentioned `pkcs12`, but please double check your keystore type.

Comment: Please check out my answer where I summarize my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to the answer of @Bruno in [How to acess jvm default KeyStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837562/how-to-acess-jvm-default-keystore) there is no default `KeyStore` in java.
That means that if you run the app with

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/app/certificates/keyStore.jks
```

this will also require to parse them in your code like

```
  private static final String filePath = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore");
  private static final String password = System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword");
```

and then use explicitly in your `HttpClient` (like in `Solution #1`).
In other words, just specifying the properties for `keyStore` is useless if you will not parse them manually and not use them for your `HttpClient`. This is what I was trying to understand when I had posted my question.

This is an important difference from system properties for `TrustStore` like

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/app/certificates/cacert
```

Specifying these properties does not require any extra code. As there is a default `TustStore` which will be created automatically by `JVM` from the properties. An then `httpClient` will just use that default `TrustStore` without any efforts from a developer.

Comment: There is something missing here.  I know for certain that defining these properties are necessary for IBM MQ, as there is no alternative.  So either MQ is getting these properties explicitly or there is some misunderstanding here.  I asked Bruno to clarify.

Comment: I particularly was interested in `io.netty` webClient.  Here is a similar discussion on this topic https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/640.

Comment: The solution mentioned by **violetagg** in the discussion should work.

Comment: I tried it and it did not work for me - WebClient still did not use the default JVM SSLContext with KeyStore.