# How can an Android application access trusted certificate placed by Intune MDM?

Tags: android, api, authentication, ssl-certificate, intune

I have Samsung tablets in my organisation that are managed by Microsoft Intune MDM. The are enrolled with Intune and are run a kiosk mode.

I need way for the tablet to authenticated to back end APIs. I have used the Intune trusted certificates feature to place a certificate on the tablet device.

I want the android app to read this certificate, sign a payload and submit the payload to an API.

How can the android app see this certificate? What android library do i use to get access to this certificate?

Please note, I don't want to use user login on the device. I simply want a way to authenticate the device.

Comment: You don't mention what is the OS version of the tablets. Have you seen/tried: [How can I get a list of trusted root certificates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40157719/295004)

Comment: The latest Android Enterprise version, so it is 9.0.

Comment: Any modern version of Android can have EMM/MDM. I would use the code in my link to get a list of certificates and look for a match, assuming no other security issues.